# Update custom user profile property using JSOM in sharepoint 2013 on prem

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, user-profile, jsom, sharepoint-rest-api

How can I update user profile property using JSOM in Sharepoint 2013 on prem. Any ways will do either by REST or JSOM.

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to do this for now, currently, read or update operations can be performed to custom properties using CSOM/PowerShell for on-premise.

Comment: How about using UserProfile.asmx service? Like stated here http://www.sharemuch.com/2012/05/13/dynamically-modify-sharepoint-user-profile-properties-with-jquery/

Comment: Not sure, i still doubt this. It may not allow you to update custom property, worth a try though

Comment: Just checked. It worked.